# Possible serial downvoting

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes

Several minutes after [posting a question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/9663/what-purpose-do-the-rubber-hairs-have-on-new-tyres) I received several downvotes on my questions:

[image]

It's not a significant amount of reputation lost but I find it suspicious.

Comment: Even to us moderators, votes are anonymous. The "suspicious voting pattern" tool didn't pick anything up. Basically, there's nothing us moderators can do to investigate further. SE staff would have to investigate, but it's probably not worth their time for something so minor.

Comment: That page gives me a list of the people who upvoted you the most, downvoted you the most and approved the most of your edits, as long as they exceed certain thresholds. It's a short list and doesn't have info about when or which posts. It's primarily intended to help find voting rings.

Comment: @freiheit: I don't understand why my last comment was deleted.

Answer (score 3):

Someone probably read your question and then followed your profile to your other contributions on the site. *Why* they downvoted is something that's impossible to know unless the voter comes forward. These specific questions have little in common that I can see.

It's disconcerting seeing these many downvotes all at once, certainly. And downvotes without explanations are particularly nasty, but Stack Exchange keeps voting anonymous for what I consider very good privacy reasons.

Since the automagic-fraudbot hasn't picked anything up, I'd suggest just letting this one go for now. If the problem gets worse, you can ask the mods here to bring it to the attention of the SE-folk.